# How is bitcoind "shy" when exchanging `version` packets?

Tags: bitcoind, network, source-code, packets

This is more of a technical/programming question.

I am referring to this line of code: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/be992701b018f256db6d64786624be4cb60d8975/src/net_processing.cpp#L1699

I understand the logic behind not sending a version packet to a newly `accept`ed connection unless they send one first, but the code I linked to does not quite do that, or does it?

At that point we are already inside an `if` block which verifies that the command received is "version", so the peer has already sent us a version packet, irrespective of who initiated the connection. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First the peer who chooses to connect shares their version.
- Each of the peers can only send one version message.

`PushNodeVersion` is used to send the version message. It is called by two functions

1) `PeerLogicValidation::InitializeNode` when the connection is outbound.

2) `ProcessMessage` when a message is received. It looks like this:

```
bool static ProcessMessage(...) {
    if (strCommand == NetMsgType::VERSION) {
        if (pfrom->fInbound)
            PushNodeVersion(pfrom, connman, GetAdjustedTime());
    }
}
```

If it was

```
    if (strCommand == NetMsgType::VERSION) {
        // If this if clause didn't exist: if (pfrom->fInbound)
            PushNodeVersion(pfrom, connman, GetAdjustedTime());
    }
```

Consider the following case:

1) Client A connects to Client B

2) Client A sends its version to Client B

3) Client B, as an answer, shares its version

Now, if that `if` caluse didn't exist, Client A would send the version message once again.

The comment `// Be shy and don't send version until we hear` is actually irrelevant.